# How to convert binary number into vector using MatLab?

Tags: matlab

The number is in binary form ( eg. )

```
 1110001010
```

make it as vector in matlab:

```
[1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0]
```

Comment: How is the number stored in MATLAB? Do you have `a=1110001010`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If the input is given as a decimal number** and if speed is essential, then the **fastest method** I can think of is:

```
num = 1110001010;
vec = mod(floor(num./ 10.^(floor(log10(num)):-1:0)),2);
```

The improvement compared to the [method provided by Rotem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42597436/7649907) combined with `num2str` is roughly 4.5x ( it's larger for higher numbers). Here is the code I used for benchmarking:

```
num = 1110001010;
niter = 1e5;

tic
for i = 1:niter
    vec = (num2str(num) == '1');
end
t1 = toc;

tic
for i = 1:niter
    vec = mod(floor(num ./ 10.^(floor(log10(num)):-1:0)),2);
end
t2 = toc;

disp(t1 / t2);
```

Of course, if the input is given as a string, then `vec = (str == '1');` is most efficient.

Comment: num = 1110001010;
vec = mod(floor(num./ 10.^(floor(log10(num)):-1:0)),2);

This one is working till num length 16, I want to apply it to a long length as 14756  number.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard answer, and one of solutions is provided for your reference.

```
a = dec2bin(906);   % a = '1110001010'
va = a-'0';       % va = [1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0];
```

Answer (score 1):

In case binary number is a string, you can convert it to logical array:

```
s = '1110001010';
S = (s == '1');
```